# accquire 'root' privilege access when with ldap remote auth

Tags: openldap

I'm setting up a box which is using remote LDAP auth for user access. For a normal group and user, it's working fine.

But I'm thinking is it possible to setup a specific group in LDAP. This group has the privilege as a local 'root'. I saw something on web talking about 'sudoers', is it the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my thought is correct. Many files are only changeable by 'root' user itself. Even I put an user in 'root' group, the user still can't change those files in any way. I'd like to drop the question.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. In 'sudoers', there is an line talking about 'rsuroot' for LDAP. Add a posixGroup as 'rsuroot' to ldap, then add the LDAP user into the group. Then the user will get 'root' access automatically when it run 'sudo cmd'